# How check incoming emails using SenderEmailAddress?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a loop to check for incoming emails from Joe Doe with specific subject. That loop works and saves attachments from Joe Doe.

```
If (Msg.SenderName = "Doe, Joe") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "Test: Smartsheet") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
```

I want to use SenderEmailAddress instead of SenderName.

```
I tested below codes:

    If (Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "test@noreplay.com") And _
            (Msg.Subject = "Test: Smartsheet") And _
            (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
```

And

```
    If (SenderEmailAddress = "test@noreplay.com") And _
            (Msg.Subject = "Test: Smartsheet") And _
            (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
```

Comment: Does Debug.Print Msg.SenderEmailAddress match what you think it is? If not, use that result.

Comment: What is `Msg`? Can you show how you are setting up `Msg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second piece of new code will definitely not work because `SenderEmailAddress` is a property of `Msg`.

For `Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "test@noreplay.com"` to return `True` there must be an exact match. "Test@noreplay.com" or "test@NoReplay.com" or any other such variation would not return `True`.

Suggestion 1:

Restore the original code but add an additional statement

```
If (Msg.SenderName = "Doe, Joe") And _
   (Msg.Subject = "Test: Smartsheet") And _
   (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
  Debug.Print Msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

After you have run the macro, the Immediate Window will contain a list of the sender email addresses of Joe Doe's emails so you can check they are as you expect.

Suggestion 2:

Make the comparison case-insensitive so:

```
If (LCase(Msg.SenderEmailAddress) = "test@noreplay.com") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "Test: Smartsheet") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` and `MailItem.SenderName` are read-only properties in the Outlook Object Model. Also note that on the MAPI level, there are half a dozen or so sender related properties, most important being the sender entry id (that is what is used for replies). Ditto for the SentRepresentingXYZ properties.
I don't think `MailItem.PorpertyAccessor.SetProperty` will let you set all of these properties.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it allows to set all sender related properties.

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set rdoMsg = Session.GetMessageFormID(Msg.EntryID)
  vSenderEntryId = Session.AddressBook.CreateOneOffEntryID("Joe The Sender", "SMTP", "joe@domain.demo", false, true)
  set vSender = Session.AddressBook.GetAddressEntryFromID(vSenderEntryId)
  rdoMsg.Sender = vSender
  rdoMsg.SentOnBehalfOf = vSender
  Msg.Save
```